# Visual Studio 2008 kills explorer /network access when saving a file on a network drive

Tags: networking, visual-studio-2008

I used to be able to open up files on my network drives with Visual Studio 2008,edit and save them fine. I could even launch whole solutions and compile them.

Just recently if I open a file up on the network map Visual studio hangs and the explorer process hangs and in the end i have to stop and restart explorer.exe and stop VS.

I can open up the same files in other programs and edit and save them instantly, it's just vs.

The network runs on 1gbs NICS, and the network drive has 15k SCSI in RAID 5. Opening up other docs or using a different program is always lighting.

What's going on with Visual Studio?!

Answer (score 1):

It was to do with the server in the end. I posted a question on server fault but i hadn't linked the two things together as the effects were different on the two machines. One couldn't access a share at all, the other had the visual studio thing.

https://serverfault.com/questions/57908/vista-clients-cant-connect-to-default-sbs-2008-share